# How to push key:value to dictionary in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dictionary

I have two HTML text input elements and one paragraph element. I have an empty javascript array and a function to push those two text input values as key:value into the array. I have a button to activate the function and print the array in the paragraph.

My javascript function is running but, the output is never producing [key:value],[key:value] but producing [object Object],[object Object]

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="t1" />
<input type="text" id="t2" />
<button id="b1" onclick="add()">Push</button>
<p id="p1"></p>
```

JavaScript :

```
var t = [];     
function add() { 
    var t1 = document.getElementById('t1').value;
    var t2 = document.getElementById('t2').value;
    t.push({key:t1, value:t2});
    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=t;
    }
```

How can I properly pushing key:value to this array and print it?

**Update** I ended up going with an `Object` syntax that looks like this:

```
const m = {}
m[1] = 2
console.log(m, m[1])
```

Comment: arrays don't have key/value pairs, but objects sort of do (property names and values).  so, t will need to be initialized as an object, ie `var t = {};`

Comment: But when declare t={ } , it produce the output as [object Object]. Not [ t1 t2 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var t = [];     
function add() { 
    var t1 = document.getElementById('t1').value;
    var t2 = document.getElementById('t2').value;
    t.push({key:t1, value:t2});
    render()
}

function render() {
  var html = '';
  t.forEach(function(element) {
    html += element['key'] +' = ' + element['value'] + '<br/>';
  })
  document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="t1" /> <input type="text" id="t2" /> <button id="b1" onclick="add()">Push</button> <p id="p1"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You push elements in array correctly, the problem is conversion to string. You can see array in console.

```
function add() { 
  var t1 = document.getElementById('t1').value;
  var t2 = document.getElementById('t2').value;
  t.push({key:t1, value:t2});
  console.log(t);
}
```

Comment: Just tried. But console produce the output as [Object]

Comment: @PrasadSrimal try to do it in chrome.

Comment: Does javascript not have a true dictionary? This is a JSON object with an _embedded_ dictionary

Comment: @javadba js has a true dictionary. it's called `Map` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map 
I don't know why the author of this question used array of object.

Comment: Thanks I did run into that .  For now I'm going to use the object syntax that is more python-like.  Arrays are about the only thing I like about python.   `const m = {};
m[1] = 2;
console.log(m, m[1])`  . The javascript syntax for `map` is  `new Map()` and `map.get()` which is more like java.

Comment: It's okay to use object for simple dictionary instead of `Map` and event more common way (if key is string).